# How to remove luma logo and replace with an other one from email

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, logo

I want to remove luma logo from email, I have tried the solution of email_transaction from admin side but It didn't work so kindly give me another solution.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Its very simple just follow below steps or link

> Step 1. Upload Your Logo On the Admin sidebar, go to Content > Design
> Configuration.
>
> Step 2. Find the store view that you want to configure and click Edit in the
> Action column.
>
> Step 3.  Under Other Settings, expand Expansion selector the Transactional
> Emails section.
>
> Step 4. To upload your prepared Logo Image, click Upload and select the file
> from your system.
>
> Step 5. In the Logo Image Alt field, enter alternate text to identify the
> image.
>
> Step 6. Enter the Logo Width and Logo Height in pixels.
>
> Step 7. Enter each value as a number, without the px abbreviation. These
> Step 8. values refer to the display dimensions of the logo in the header, and
> not to the actual size of the image.

[image]

**Official Magento Link**

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/email-template-configuration.html

Please don't forget to refresh cache.

Comment: Love you brother, using your links I got Idea how to modify email header. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the "Luma Logo", follow these steps from the [DevDocs](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/email-template-configuration.html):

1. On the Admin sidebar, go to Content > Design > Configuration.
2. Find the store view that you want to configure and click Edit in the Action column.
3. Under Other Settings, expand Expansion selector the Transactional Emails section.
4. To upload your preferred Logo Image, click Upload and select the file from your system.
5. In the Logo Image Alt field, enter alternate text to identify the image.
6. Enter the Logo Width and Logo Height in pixels.

- **If you simply want to remove the logo, then enter "0" for the width and height. Click "Save Configuration"**

Comment: You answer is alright, but It was not working for me. thanks for answering. as my logo was not uploading through that way.

Comment: @MuhammadAli You may need to go to System > Cache Management and then click FLUSH MAGENTO CACHE. Also, you want to make sure that you are in the correct Store View. Hope that helps!